# Permission Denial media documents provider

Tags: android, image, path, gallery

I want to choose a picture from the gallery and then save the path. I use this path to show the images in a `RecyclerView`. I use `Picasso` to download the image in the `ImageView`. The problem I have is the following:

when I choose the image is correctly shown in the `RecyclerView`, but if I leave the screen and come back, I get this error:

01-19 15:05:18.984 542-840/? W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ... requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS

and the image is not shown anymore. This is my code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>


 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getMainActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Choose Image Source");
    builder.setItems(new CharSequence[] {"Gallery"},
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                            Intent intent;
                            // GET IMAGE FROM THE GALLERY
                            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);   // Show local files only (available since honeycomb, sdkVersion 11)

                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a picture"), Constants.REQUEST_CHOOSE_PHOTO);
                }
            });

    builder.show();


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ImageDb image = new ImageDb();
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {  
            case Constants.REQUEST_CHOOSE_PHOTO:
                image.setImageFilePath(data.getData().toString());

                break;
        }
        images.add(image);
    }
}


 @BindingAdapter({"url", "size"})
public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url, float size) {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(url)) {
        Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).resize((int) size, (int) size).centerCrop().into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Does someone know where is the problem??Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want to choose a picture from the gallery and then save the path

That is not going to work. When you use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, [you have *temporary* rights to use the `Uri` that you get back](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Also note that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not take a `Uri` in the `Intent`. Get rid of `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`.

> Does someone know where is the problem?

You are attempting to use the `Uri` that you get back later. The instance component (in this case, the activity) that receives the `Uri` has rights to use it, but nothing else in your app does.

In some situations, you can propagate your access rights to other component instances. For example, suppose Activity A has the code from your question, and in there you call `startActivity()` to start Activity B. Activity B will not have access to the content identified by the `Uri` by default. But, Activity A could add the `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag to the `Intent` it uses with `startActivity()`, and pass along read access to Activity B.

But, other forms of navigation (e.g., BACK button) do not offer this, let alone persisting the `Uri` as a string and trying to use it tomorrow or next week.

If you switch to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` on Android 4.4+, you can try to use `takePersistableUriPermission()` on `ContentResolver`, in which case you may get durable access to that content.

Otherwise, if you are looking for long-term access to the content, you need to copy the content (e.g., copy the image) into storage that you control (e.g., [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html)).